# Why and how do DNS queries over my ISP resolve to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: networking, dns

This happens with some frequency with certain sites - even with well-known sites like facebook, wikipedia, duckduckgo. Today I'm having this problem with reddit. Using `dig` gives the following:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 www.reddit.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u1-Debian <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.reddit.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 32320
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.reddit.com.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.reddit.com.         84153   IN      A       127.0.0.1

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       55594   IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       55594   IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       55594   IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       55594   IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       55594   IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       55594   IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       55594   IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       55594   IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       55594   IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       55594   IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       55594   IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       55594   IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       55594   IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
localhost.              604411  IN      A       127.0.0.1
localhost.              604411  IN      AAAA    ::1

;; Query time: 585 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Sep 10 09:55:57 AEST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 323
```

I get the same response with 8.8.4.4 as well as Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 (except for TTL and times / dates), and although I didn't try it in this instance, this has in the past happened with OpenNIC's DNS servers as well.

I can ssh into my VPS and run the exact same command, and it works! Using the DNS provided by my ISP also works. So what's happening? Is it possible that I've misconfigured my system somehow? Is my ISP actually intercepting DNS requests to return garbage, or could it be just a misconfiguration on their end? I have only ever seen this affect one site at a time and the problem typically resolves within a few hours, but today it seems to be taking unusually long.

Comment: I suppose it could be malware on your computer. Does some kind of malware-looking process have a listener on  port 80 or 443 on 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Could you show the answer section (if any) of `dig @8.8.8.8 chaos txt hostname.bind` and `dig @8.8.8.8 chaos txt id.server` the next time this starts to happen?